# elementByCss failure after hasElementByCss success in Intern

Tags: intern

Can anyone explain why I get an "Error: Error response status: 7." when I run the following in an Intern functional test?

```
.hasElementByCss("#COLUMN1_HEADER > span")
.then(function(result) {
    console.log("Test #2a - Check column header");
    assert(result == true, "Could not find COLUMN1_HEADER in Test #2a");
})
.elementByCss("#COLUMN1_HEADER > span")
    .moveTo()
    .click()
    .end()
```

Note that I'm checking for the existence of an element (which is found, and does exist) and then attempt to move to it and click on it.

I've used some console.log calls to ensure that it is definitely failing on the ".elementByCss" line. What's interesting is that there is a whole bunch of keyboard driven tests above this section of the test and if I comment those out then it passes.

What I don't understand is how "hasElementByCss" and "elementByCss" with the same CSS selector can yield different results, and what effect the keyboard tests have.

Comment: This appears to be caused by having used the .active() method earlier in the test... does elementByCss only search within the element returned from it's callback?

Comment: The use of the has methods is strongly discouraged; you will know whether or not an element exists based on whether or not the `elementByCss` command succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by working my way back through the test code and ensuring that I had called .end() after previously having used .active() ... I have no idea whether this is a workaround or if this is expected behaviour - but it doesn't appear particularly clear. I would personally consider this to be a bug.

Comment: It is expected. Once you have retrieved an element, that becomes the root context for future requests unless you call `end`. This is just like how jQuery DOM methods work, and is not a defect.